# Secure channel without identifying information

Tags: tls, ssh

Is there a way to establish a secure channel like ssl or ssh without leaking identifying information to an observer, especially the server's public key? Are there real implementations?

Comment: Define "identifying information." For example, you have an IP address at the very least...

Comment: The name "public key" is from the adjective "public" so there is no point in not exposing it.

Comment: @Jakuje Public key means exposing it doesn't lead to hacking. But it leaks privacy informations. For example, if you connect to a public hotspot and then connect to your own VPN then you are not so anonymous anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the security of an SSL/SSH channel: identity and security-against-eavesdropping.

If you want to not leak "identifying information," then you have **no way** to establish identity....... because that information is literally not there.

You **can**, however, establish communications secure from prying eyes by using a random key for every conversation. However, you won't be able to verify it's who you think it is, so you open yourself up to a MITM attack.

You COULD do something clever where you have a pre-shared secret and each side issues the other a challenge to sign a random, non-repeating identifier (like a guid). If both sides return the correctly-signed value, then both sides know they have previously shaken hands. I don't know if there's any standard like this anywhere.

Comment: Well, a secure channel vulnerable to MitM is not secure.

Comment: @SmitJohnth It's secure in a different way. See my edits.